# Get static variable from object property (string)

Tags: php, class

How do I get a static variable dynamically?

I'm trying this but getting the dreaded PAAMAYIM error:

```
foreach($this->entity::$dialog_data as $property) {
```

Should result in `Company::$dialog_data` because `$this->entity` contains the string `'Company'`.

Answer (score 1):

maybe its help you

```
$temp = $this->entity;
foreach($temp::$dialog_data as $property) {
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid any temp variables.

Comment: i think there is no another way

Comment: @sikfire i searching and read somewhere this is possible only with temp variable